# Is it possible to use infer on a type with generic parameters without it resulting in unknowns?

Tags: typescript

Take this example

```
const head = <T>(list: T[]) => list[0]

type ParamType = typeof head extends (list: infer P) => any ? P : never;
// type ParamType = unknown[]
```

This results in `ParamType` being `unknown[]`.

Is there a way to make `infer` be aware of `P`'s type parameter so that `ParamType` becomes a type with type parameter `T`? Doing that would result in

```
type ParamType<T> = T[]
```

Comment: It is not possible. `T` is fully unknown type at the level of definition of `head` function. You need to have existing type instead of type constructor, as `typeof head` is type constructor not a type. Take a look - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgUwIYBMYF4YB4AqA+ACgBsBLaALhhwG0BdASgzxlOmoAZaBYAKCgE8ADghgAFJACckAWxxCEWABLIUzTMtQwEADygIwKCDGJkolEmABmCCWMbpmSMPxgB+MTEpgEANxsBuXl4BYRgAQQwxSRk5YSwCJEpoCQsAc3tmZLTmAHocmCywVJgkIwB3EUFSoxCEYPkYACFI8SlZeSxakEt4FVz8gFcwAGswEDKwOhLyyuqYWphQSCgJAeAoEAkgA

Comment: There's no way to do this purely at the type level; a detour through value-level code can [force the compiler to compute it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgUwIYBMYF4YB4AqA+ACgBsBLaALhhwG0BdASgzxlOmoAZaAoYIpCCDAAiAVwC2YgJ4BhPgNzMA3lxgwADgCcSANyRQEMUJCgaRwKCA0FGimAF8VMFOKkAFDSDUYYBMCKJEAIQw-NgAgoTAAEaUBEiUYQA0MAB0aUgaAOYQlEhgkozozHkFTD6FzGH0BIio9ArWANxcDlCSagauGUhiOO0ICt6iEjJyEArUAETOI+6ek7SNQA) but it's ugly and doesn't scale well. I'd recommend manually writing `type ParamType<T>=T[]` unless there's some use case that prohibits it. If you want I'll write that up.

Comment: Is there a fundamental reason why this isn't possible? I don't see why it shouldn't be other than the fact that it just hasn't been implemented in the TS type system. It should in principle be doable just by looking at the type system. Am I missing something?